# Имеется ли родство между словами "речь" и "река"?

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Речь - поток слов, река - поток воды. Ранее говорили - "рек", в смысле "сказывал". Сохранилось слово "изрек".
Родственны ли эти лексемы?

Answer (score 0):

Не похоже. 
"Речь" - производное от древнерусского ["реку" (rekti)](https://semenov.academic.ru/1017/%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C). 
"Река" - то ли от [тюркского "reka"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F), то ли от древнего названия Волги [Ra-aha](https://www.proza.ru/2013/05/30/845)
В целом это два разных слова, но так исторически сложилось, что у них получилось близкое звучание и местами пересекающееся значение.

Comment: Ваши источники, мягко говоря, сомнительные. Ни один видный этимолог, включая Фасмера и Черных, о тюркском происхождении «реки» и слова не говорили. Все в один голос выделяют тут индоевропейский корень, от которого произошёл гидроним «Рейн», например.

Comment: Крылов - https://gufo.me/dict/krylov/%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0 предлагает латинское "rivus". Трубачев - http://annales.info/slav/small/etimologia.htm как раз говорит о rěka, впрочем, там все запутанно.

Comment: Но ни Крылов, ни Трубачёв ничего не говорят о тюркском происхождении слова «река».

Comment: По ссылке указано предположение, что это заимствование из тюркских языков. Этимология самого слова "река" вообще отдельный и, судя по всему, большой и спорный вопрос, который не имеет отношения к рекаVSречь

Comment: Относительно исторического корня в слове "река"[Острожская библия](http://history.org.ua/LiberUA/e_dzherela_Biblia_2006/e_dzherela_Biblia_2006.pdf)
Откр.12:15
"ї испусти змїи за женою изъ устъ своихъ воду яко р**ѣ**ку, да ю в р**е**цѣ потопитъ. страница 1912

Comment: Можете пальцем показать, где Трубачёв или Крылов говорят о таком предположении?

Comment: @Пересвет я ктому, что если Вам кто-то скажет, что слово река писалось ранее через "ѣ", а слово речь через "е" - Не верьте! Река писалось через "ѣ" со времён петровской реформы и до революции 1917

Comment: @Пересвет выше ссылка на Вики. Куда еще показать?

Comment: В Википедии нет ссылки на источник.